# How to solve this mysqli_stmt::get_result() fatal php error?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using php version 5.6 and also i check box mysqlnd but code not working in 3 place 1) config.php and 2) login.php 3) index.php

Its showing me error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() config.php on line 21

Config.php code:

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    ob_start();
    include __DIR__."/db.php";
    include __DIR__."/masud.php";
    $_IM = array
        (
            'sitename'   => "Site Name",
            'siteurl'    => "http://example.com/",
        );

    if( isset( $_SESSION['uid']))
    {
        $uid = base64_decode( $_SESSION['uid']);
        $user = $idb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
        $user->bind_param("s", $uid);
        $user->execute();
        $user_r = $user->get_result();
        if( $user_r->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $users = $user_r->fetch_assoc();
        }
    }
```

On Line 21 Code:

```
$user_r = $user->get_result();
```

Login.php Code:

```
    <?php 

    include "./includes/config.php";
    $title = "Login";
    include "./includes/header.php";
    if( isset( $_SESSION['uid']))
    {
        header("Location:dashboard");
        exit("LOL");
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['sublogin']))
    {
        $email = iclean( $_POST['email'] );
        $pass = iclean( $_POST['pass'] );
        $login = $idb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
        $login->bind_param("s", $email);
        $login->execute();
        $login_r = $login->get_result();
        if( $login_r->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $login_f = $login_r->fetch_assoc();
            if( $login_f['pass'] == md5($pass))
            {
                $_SESSION['uid'] = base64_encode( $login_f['id']);
                header("Location:dashboard");
                exit("LOL");
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = "Invalid Password";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "Invalid Email OR Password";
        }
    }
?>
```

error in 18 line Code:

```
$login_r = $login->get_result();
```

index.php Code:

```
<?php
$r = $idb->query("SELECT * FROM recharge ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");
while( $rf = $r->fetch_assoc())
{
?>
```

Please help me to solve it.Thanks

Comment: try `$stmt->fetch()` rather than `$stmt->get_result()`?

Comment: In config.php you are doing `if( isset( $_SESSION['uid']))` , which i think not correct (i don't think at that time any session is creates,because session need to be created after successfully login). BTW `$stmt->get_result()` need to be `$stmt->fetch()`

Comment: thanks for reply but i don't understand

Comment: @MasudRana  change  `$user_r = $user->get_result();` to `$user_r = $user->fetch();` in `config.php` and so on in all other codes correspondingly

Comment: Strange. In my php manual ( 5.3.2 ) there is no `get_result()` method but on the PHP site it suggests there is( http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php ). However, there is a comment on that page `Please note that this method requires the mysqlnd driver. Othervise you will get this error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`

Comment: not working @AlivetoDie

Comment: New error message?

Comment: after set this `$user_r = $user->fetch();` i can't login. showing me `Invalid Email OR Password` but my email, pass is correct.